# Skip database on import of MySQL dumpfile

Tags: mysql

I created a dumpfile with this command:

```
mysqldump -p3307 --quick -u root --password="password" --all-databases > all_databases04292011.sql
```

I then attempted to import this dumpfile into a new MySQL server, however it fails trying to write to the `information_schema` database. Is there a way to skip this database on import?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a program editing the `all_databases04292011.sql` dumpfile, to delete all the records in `information_schema` database.

It is not that hard, since the dumpfile is well structured.

Just open `all_databases04292011.sql` using your favourite editor, then find

```
--
-- Current Database: `information_schema`
--
```

Delete every line below this until you see the next

```
--
-- Current Database: `xxxxxx`
--
```

Comment: I do not know how to program, could you provide me an example to get me started?